# Will only internal domain requests be routed through my VPN setup?

Tags: vpn, dns, routing

I'm using a Cisco VPN client to connect to the VPN for my work, and I'm curious how it actually works. From what I've been able to tell, regular requests (e.g. google.com) don't go through the VPN, but requests to servers in my company network (e.g. jenkins) do go through the VPN.

Looking through my network adapters, I see that there is an attribute "Connection-specific DNS Suffix", which lists my work DNS. However, my research into this wasn't super clear.

I want to be 100% certain that "regular" internet traffic won't be routed through the VPN (so I can leave it connected on my personal computer, as I often have to do stuff late at night, but I don't want to keep reconnecting/disconnecting for fear of having personal traffic routed through it).

Here is the config:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 7:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MyCompanyName.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::25fc:fa68:25aa:238f%52(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.100.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1493173658
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.1.4
                                       172.21.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Windows will send all traffic down the VPN tunnel, even to locations that aren't on the VPN.

What you're looking for is "Split Tunneling", which is when only some of the data goes down the VPN tunnel.

The best way to find out exactly what's going on is to connect to your VPN and then type `netstat -r` into command prompt. Look for the Network Destination that equals `0.0.0.0` in the Routing Table as this is your default route. All packets for destinations not established in the routing table are sent via the default route.

If the Gateway/Interface equals your local router/local interface, then "Split Tunneling" is in place and not everything is going via the VPN tunnel. If it shows a VPN interface/gateway then it's likely all the traffic is going via your VPN.

You may however have multiple `0.0.0.0` default routes like me. If you take a look at my computer's Routing Table you will see my local interface and my virtual interface on the VPN (10.198.167.242).

`Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.2    366
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    10.198.167.242     31`

This is where the Metric comes into play. The metric for my VPN interface (10.198.167.242) is lower, so in theory everything (bar some LAN addresses) is sent via my VPN connection.

I won't go into how to manipulate your PC's Routing Table  here, but I'm sure a quick Google into how to modify the metrics will probably assist you with what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, there was only one 0.0.0.0 entry and it was for my router, so it looks like I'm good. Is split tunneling setup on the client or the vpn server? I don't see any options related to it in my client connection config file (it .pcf file for cisco)

Comment: "Split Tunneling" may not necessarily be a setting in the client as it is more of a concept that you can implement/manipulate yourself.